# Cucumber outline type conversation

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I going to test the class method which get the integer as parameter:

```
def step(response)
   if response < 10
```

I create cucumber scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: submit guess
    Given the code "<code>"
    When I response "<answer>"
    Then the result should be "<result>"

    Scenarios: level one
    | code | answer | result |
    |   1  |    2   |    3   |
    |   5  |    4   |    9   |
```

And the step difinitions:

```
When /^I response "([^"]*)"$/ do  | response |
  @result = @game.step(response)
end
```

When I'm running the test I get error, because the cucumber pass the parameter to my method as String.

How can I fix it?

I can fix the class method code:

```
def step(response)
   response = response.to_i
   if response < 10
```

but it will break all my existing code.

Comment: see - http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/cucumber-step-argument-transforms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber always pass string parameters to your step definitions and it is step definition responsibility to convert parameter to appropriate type. You need to do this:

```
When /^I response "([^"]*)"$/ do  | response |
  @result = @game.step(response.to_i)
end
```